# sugarcrm community edition advice

Tags: sugarcrm

I am wondering as of what server is better to run sugarCRM community edition ? 
Centos , debian or ubuntu ?
I have a choice between the 3. 
any suggestions would be appreciated 
thank you

Comment: Better way is use "ubuntu" with PHP 5.6 version.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't matter either way, just be sure you are running the latest version of PHP 5.3 for the best performance.